# Computing the matrix $T$ using the basis $\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $T(f(x)) = f(1) + f'(0)x + (f'(0)+f''(0))x^2$, and I need to compute the matrix of this linear transformation in base $\beta$, which is the standard ordered basis of $P_2(R)$ (namely $(1,x,x^2)$).
I have tried doing it but I get the wrong coordinates and now I don't really know how to properly calculate them.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute $T(1)=1$, $T(x)=1+x+x^2$ and $T(x^2)=2+2x^2$.  These are the columns.   That is,

> $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&2\\0&1&0\\0&1&2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Could you show me how you get to those results? I only got it right for $T(1)$.

Comment: Yeah.  When $f(x)=x$, you need $f'(x)=1$ and $f''(x)=0$.  Similarly $f(x)=x^2\implies f'(x)=2x$ and $f''(x)=2$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thank you so much.